# create hexagonal cells grid using lat/lon coordinates

Tags: r, spatial, r-grid

I would like to create a spatial grid with hexagonal cells using WGS84 coordinates (ie cells defined by 2 coordinates X=Latitude and Y=Longitude)

So, this is what I was thinkin about :

```
library(ggplot2);library(hexbin)
X<-seq(-10,20,by=0.1) # create coordinates vectors X and Y
Y<-seq(35,65,by=0.1)
z<-rnorm(301,0.5,1)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y,z)) # create data frame with a z value for each cells (X,Y)
pl<-ggplot2(data=mat,aes(x=X,y=Y,z=z))+stat_summury_hex(fun=function(x) sum(x))
plot(pl)
```

But doing this does not provide what I wanted.

So, my question is : how to do a spatial grid with hexagonal cells using lat/lon coordinates ?

And second question : how to create a grid centered from one point (that would represent the centroid, and not the left bottom corner as usual?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand properly, you're looking for `expand.grid()`:

```
xy <- expand.grid(X=X,Y=Y)
z<-rnorm(nrow(xy),0.5,1)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(xy,z)) # create data frame with a z value for each cells (X,Y)
head(df)
pl<-ggplot(data=df,aes(x=X,y=Y,z=z))+stat_summary_hex(fun=function(x) sum(x))
plot(pl)
```

[image]

As for the second question, I'm not sure, but since all hexagons are the same size and will require the same operation to center, you can shift them uniformly by changing `X` and `Y` appropriately. Perhaps this can also be done via arguments also, not sure.

[[Edit July 23]]
second question was how to get a `data.frame` of hex coordinates. Took some digging, but here's an example:

```
library(hexbin)
coords <- hcell2xy( hexbin(x=X,y=Y))
head(coords)
      x        y
1 -10.0 35.00000
2  -9.5 35.86603
3  -8.5 35.86603
4  -9.0 36.73205
5  -8.0 36.73205
6  -7.5 37.59808
```

`hcell2xy()` is the key function called by `ggplot2`, and you may need to be explicit about specifying the argument `xbins`, which is determined automatically inside `ggplot2`, but appears to default to 30 in both cases.

[[Edit 3, to include z level]]
This is an answer to the comment asking for z levels as well. Ripped from `ggplot2:::hexBin`

```
hb <- hexbin(x=X,y=Y)
# Convert to data frame
data.frame(
        hcell2xy(hb), 
        count = hb@count, 
        density = hb@count / sum(hb@count, na.rm=TRUE)
)
```

You can choose whether to use `count` or `density` for colors later, but warning: those are different from your `z` variable fed to `ggplot2`. If you'd like to summarize based on some other statistic, then I suggest you also look into the guts of those functions to see how things are passed around. That's what I've been doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for.
But I'm wondering how I can get the hexacells into a dataframe (ie get the same dataframe than 'df' but with coordinates of my hexagonal cells).
that I can not handle for doing analyses with other files such as raster, dataframe...etc
So, basically, how can I retrieve a dataframe from "stat_summary_hex(fun=function(x) sum(x))" ?

Comment: as I said before (but simultaneously with tim riffe!), I would like to handle my hexagonal cells as a classical dataframe. Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: like, you want a df of the coordinates of the six corners of each hex cell?

Comment: for instance, but I think a more proper way to get the hexa cells coordinates would be done by using the lat/lon of the centroïd... ?!

Comment: @Remssssss please see edit to answer. It took some deep digging in the code, but found it. The final asnwer was found in: `?hexbin:::hcell2xy`

Comment: Thanks Tim, I approved your answer. 
However, how can i retrieve the z value calculated with stat_summary_hex() function ?