# How to divide 2D coordinates into hexagonal cells?

Tags: java, geometry, hexagonal-tiles

Given a set of x's (latitude) and y's (longitude), I would like to be able to assign (hash) them to their corresponding hexagonal cells, which would cover all points within that set. How would I go about doing that in Java or C?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839423/create-hexagonal-cells-grid-using-lat-lon-coordinates) is close to what I'd like to do, but not in Python, plus I'm not necessarily interested in graphical representation.

Comment: Here is example of building hexagonal grid over rectangle (in your case bounding rectangle of all points): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876288/calculate-size-of-hexagons-to-fit-inside-rectangle/36881620#36881620